# How can I permantently disable the keyboard toggle in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, locale

It seems like every day or so, I hit some sort of key sequence that changes the keyboard mapping to something unexpected - for example, ctrl-s now produces ß instead of saving.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: This has something to do with the language bar.  For example by default Left Alt + Shift switches between input languages.  A key combination you'll easily hit when using VS shortcuts.  Ask more about it at superuser.com

Comment: It's only affecting Visual Studio, not other programs.